# What is the best way to find plagiarism in a draft research?

Tags: plagiarism

Recently I got a research from one of my colleagues. However, I suspect the draft of his work and think it is extracted from somewhere else and it is not a new research in the field of cryptography. I need to know due to the lack of the time I have can I make sure about this issue? what are the solutions for this?

Comment: Do you suspect that the text is plagiarized? (That's relatively easy to check for.) Or that the idea is plagiarized (much harder to find out)?

Comment: And _why_ do you suspect? There is something a bit fishy about this scenario...

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you suspect was plagiarised, how and where from.

If you believe the ideas/structure/references (the latter would apply to a literature review) have been plagiarised, you're only recourse is to use your expertise and knowledge of the field to identify the sources. A literature survey of your own would help this.

If, as I suspect, you mean the text has been plagiarised, you can use services such as [Turnitin](http://turnitin.com/) and [iThenticate](http://www.ithenticate.com/) (as suggested by others). If you work in a university, it is very likely that they already subscribe to one of those services, and you should be able to access it. Very often, universities provide (password-protected) access for students to check their work through such services, prior to submission; usually through their virtual learning environment (VLE, e.g. Moodle, Blackboard). Your librarians would be able to point you in the right direction.

However, there's a much easier way: just Google (and Google Book search aned Google Scholar search) the text you suspect of being copied. Pretty much the only sources Turnitin *et al.* have access to that Google doesn't is previously submitted student assignments; so (as I read this case) Google is as likely as anywhere to identify the source of any suspect passages.

I just picked a random sentence from a nearby textbook to test this. While ["straight" Google didn't pick it up](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&ei=EI6UWt64C-bYgAaIz564CQ&q=the%20operations%20of%20rotation%2C%20mirror%20reflection%2C%20and%20inversion%20through%20a%20point%20%28see%20below%29%20are%20point-symmetry%20operations%2C%20since%20each%20leaves%20at%20least%20one%20point%20of%20the%20object%20in%20a%20fixed%20position&oq=the%20operations%20of%20rotation%2C%20mirror%20reflection%2C%20and%20inversion%20through%20a%20point%20%28see%20below%29%20are%20point-symmetry%20operations%2C%20since%20each%20leaves%20at%20least%20one%20point%20of%20the%20object%20in%20a%20fixed%20position&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1350.49772.0.50516.254.161.19.4.4.0.190.10258.70j38.108.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..123.43.3624.0..0j46j0i131k1j0i46k1j0i10k1j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.0.zqNgtIEZIiQ), [**Google Books did**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=the%20operations%20of%20rotation%2C%20mirror%20reflection%2C%20and%20inversion%20through%20a%20point%20%28see%20below%29%20are%20point-symmetry%20operations%2C%20since%20each%20leaves%20at%20least%20one%20point%20of%20the%20object%20in%20a%20fixed%20position).

When I was a fresher, and we had our "don't plagiarise" lecture, I remember the lecturer telling us that the university subscribed to all these expensive anti-plagiarism services, but the lecturers just used Google instead.

Comment: Thank you, if I use this research ( it was a part of a collaboration with a partner of the university) and submit it to an academic conference, what can happen if the research has plagiarism? Can I, for example, submit with a different name and after acceptance and when I make sure about the plagiarism issue, change the author name, University of the article?

Comment: @Berliner, no, do not use any deceptive practices in paper submission. Absolutely not.

Answer (score 1):

Use a plagiarism detection program. The two I'm most familiar with are [Turnitin](http://turnitin.com/) and [iThenticate](http://www.ithenticate.com/). There are plenty of others - just Google for "plagiarism detection".

Comment: Thank you but is there any free/trial ones?

Comment: "just Google for "plagiarism detection"" Literally :)